# Backup of files in XP Mode application

Tags: windows, backup

I've recently installed a 16 bit application in Windows XP mode on our HR department's desktop and I'm looking for ideas to backup the system up. Only one folder requires backing up.

The desktop is shut down at night so we need a way to backup the data during the day before, while or after she's finishing using it.  I was wondering if anyone has got any suggestions?

The folder is only 160MB and there are 5697 Files.

Comment: If it's just a folder of files, I'd just put it on Dropbox. Why'd you put ServerFault in the title?

Comment: I didn't know I did put server fault in the title.  Its sensitive data so I don't want to put it in the cloud.  All Human Resource information such as bank details, address ect..

Answer (score 0):

Windows backup to a network share in a scheduled job seems like a pretty straightforward answer.

Or, if it's just files that you're worried about, a logoff or shutdown script that does an `xcopy` would be equally effective.

Comment: Can Windows backup password protect the data? Does it backup lots of small files quick?